# Can/Should a question be moved once it has been answered?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

[This question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/227840/reset-windows-and-now-minecraft-will-not-open) is having issues with Minecraft after a PC reset (I believe it roughly equates to a format). Depending on what the solution is, it's possible that this question might be better suited on perhaps SuperUser.

For the most part, once a question has been answered, it's pretty much given the "[status-completed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-completed)" badge and ignored for further reference (I see this a lot with off-topic or unclear questions).

So, depending in the cause of the issue, once the question has been answered correctly, should it be moved, or just left here?

Comment: By what definition should that question be directed to SuperUser?

It is a question about installing a game, but that comes under the definition of [tag:technical-issues].

The user has put in system specifications, but only after I requested, as is requested in the technical issues

Comment: It's possible that the issue may not involve the game at all, just the functionality of his pc after the reset. Sure, Minecraft is *affected* but it isn't the *problem*.

Comment: Any software issue should be fixed by a windows reset. I fail to see how a windows reset could cause a hardware issue..

But I think saying "this question does not belong here, because I have assessed, personally, that OP is not having the problem they say they are" is unfair. If you think the question does not belong here, you should flag it to be closed.

Comment: @Timelord64 To clarify: while yes; I have used this as an example, the question I have asked is broader than that. I'm asking *in general*. Also I think you are misreading the question - I have stated *"Depending on what the **solution** is..."*. This question is regarding the "on-topicness" of the question *after* it has been defined that the issue is actually off-topic (following the rules of what is and isn't off- topic). I'm not in any way trying to say "I think this is off-topic". (And regardless, if I did, it would still go to a vote - so no harm done).

Comment: A reminder on migration rules; for a question to be a good migration candidate, it needs to not just be on topic on another site (or *more* on topic, as the case may be), but also **off topic** on the site on which it was originally posted.

Answer (score 2):

The basic rule of thumb for problemetic questions is this:

> Take the question.  Remove the game from the question.  Does the problem still exist?  If so, chances are pretty good it doesn't belong here.

Whether a question has an answer is irrelevant; the decision is based on the question itself.

For this particular one...I think it'd be acceptable if it stayed here.  It needs more engagement from the asker to proper answer, however.